# The gravitational force between two spheres of equal mass

Tags: newtonian-mechanics, forces, newtonian-gravity

Two spheres(identical) of mass "m" and radius "R" are separated by 3R from their centres. The forces between them is proportional to:

1. $R^{-2}$

   when  $ F = \frac{Gmm}{(3R)^2}$
2. $R^{4}$

   when $m$ has been replaced by $\frac{4}{3}\pi R^2\rho$

My teacher insisted that the second one is right, but what is the actual notation[which one should I follow].

Comment: The problem, as stated by you, is ambiguous. What is being kept constant? Mass, density, radius?

Comment: Your formula for mass in part 2. is incorrect.

Comment: If I understand you correctly, the question is not how the force changes with the distance between the two objects - which would be 1.

Instead, the question is how the force between two spheres of constant density,  radius R, and distance 3R scale with the radius R itself, which gives you answer 2 as correctly pointed out by @Not_Einstein

Answer (score 2):

The mass of each sphere is 4$\rho\pi$$R^3$/3, assuming $\rho$ is a constant. Substituting this into your first equation, F is proportional to $R^3$$R^3$/$R^2$ which equals $R^4$ as in the second choice.

Your equation for F is correct, it's just that the dependence of each mass on R is not explicitly shown so it suggests that the force goes as 1/$R^2$.